# Android activity's all appear on the same line

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I got a problem with my xml code in Android Studio.

For some reason this xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/textview"/>
    <!-- Set OnClickListener to trigger results when pressed -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Displays keyboard when touched -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />
    <!-- This nested layout contains views of its own -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Set OnClickListener to trigger results when pressed -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/button" />
        <!-- Shows an image from your drawable resources -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <!-- Closing tag for the horizontal nested layout -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Displays keyboard when touched -->

</LinearLayout>
```

All apears on the same line when I run my app.

How do i make it go to the next line under each other just like a br tag in html.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add 
`android:orientation="vertical"`
to the first (outer) `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Please mark as solved then so it will help other users in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For LinearLayout:

> The default orientation is horizontal.

Just set orientation in main layout to:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

Answer (score 1):

**LinearLayout**

> A Layout that arranges its children in a single column or a single
>   row. The direction of the row can be set by calling setOrientation().
>   You can also specify gravity, which specifies the alignment of all the
>   child elements by calling setGravity() or specify that specific
>   children grow to fill up any remaining space in the layout by setting
>   the weight member of LinearLayout.LayoutParams. **The default
>   orientation is horizontal.**

This is why you got everything on the same line.